# Convert date format using php

Tags: php, string, date

I have the following string in php which is a date:

"05/06/2013"

I need it to be in the following format:

06-MAY-13

Whichever method I use needs to be able to handle any date given in the first format and convert it into the desired format.

How could I do this in php?

Thanks

Comment: http://in3.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 2):

By using [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) and [`date()`](http://php.net/date).  Spefically:

```
echo date('d-M-y', strtotime('05/06/2013'));
```

Replace `M` with `F` if you want the full name of the month.

Answer (score 1):

```
date("d-F-y",strtotime("05/06/2013"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it with the [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) Class.

```
$Date = new DateTime("05/03/2013");
echo $Date->format("d-M-Y");
```